# Vertically align text in cell with tabularx and multirow

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, tabularx

I am making a table with multiple rows and I need to vertically align the contents of the cells that I show in the image. I've tried a few things like modifying the *\vspace* but can't get it to work properly. Does anyone know how can I do ?? Thank you very much!!

```
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{table}[!ht]
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|p{1cm}|Y|m{2cm}|}
\hline
\textbf{Task} & \textbf{Description} & \textbf{Points} \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{1cm}{\textbf{TX.x}} & \multicolumn{1}{Y|}{\textbf{Test Header}} & \multirow[b]{2}{2cm}{\centering Example} \\ \cline{2-2}
 & \multicolumn{1}{X|}{\lipsum[1]} &  \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: ab]

Comment: \multirow{14} should work in this specific case. The number refers to the number of lines of text as opposed to the number of table rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{table}[!ht]
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|p{1cm}|Y|m{2cm}|}
\hline
\textbf{Task} & \textbf{Description} & \textbf{Points} \\ \hline
\multirow{17}{1cm}{\textbf{TX.x}} & \multicolumn{1}{Y|}{\textbf{Test Header}} & \multirow{17}{2cm}{\centering Example} \\ \cline{2-2}
 & \multicolumn{1}{X|}{\lipsum[1]} &  \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why 17 in \multirow{17}?

Comment: the centre column has more rows than two --therefore an approximation to center the side columns--if the centre coln also had two rows probably not required

Comment: The contents in the middle column occupy a total of 19 rows. If you specify `\multirow{17}`, the contents in teh first and last column will not be exactly vertically centered.

Answer (score 3):

With `multirow`, you have to count the number of lines. If you want to specify a position relatively to a number of rows (of the tabular), we may use `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` and its command `\Block`. Moreover, you only have to use the key `hvlines` to draw all the expected rules.

The `X` column is similar to the `X` column of `{tabularx}` of the package `tabularx` (you need `nicematrix` ≥ 6.0).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!ht]
\centering
\begin{NiceTabular}{w{c}{1cm}Xw{c}{2cm}}[hvlines]
\RowStyle{\bfseries}
Task & \centering Description & Points \\ 
\Block{2-1}{TX.x} & \centering \bfseries Test Header & \Block{2-1}{Example} \\ 
 & \lipsum[1] &  \\ 
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 3):

You don't really need to use `multirow`. Here is a simpler code, redefining the X column type as `m{}` instead of `p`:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{tabularx, ragged2e, caption, lipsum}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalsize\bfseries}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!ht]
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|>{\centering\bfseries}p{1cm}|X|>{\centering\bfseries\arraybackslash}m{2cm}|}
\hline
Task & \thead{Description} & Points \\ \hline
 & \thead{Test Header} & \\ \cline{2-2}
TX.x & \lipsum[1] & Example \\
 \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

- `multirow` cells have their content at the vertical center of cell. It is at center of declared number of the text lines in adjacent table columns, which are spanned by them
- In your MWE you declare only two text lines, but there are 14 of them
- Recent version of `multirow` cells has option `=`, which overtake declared width of column (see MWE below).

Off-topic:

- For column headers is used `\thead` macro from the `makecell` package.
- For additional vertical space around cells' contents is used `\makegapedcells` macro, defined also defined in `makecell` package.
- Removed are all `multicolumn{1}{...}{...}` cells, They are superfluous.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{makecell, multirow, tabularx} % <---
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize\bfseries} % <---
\renewcommand\theadgape{} % <---
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \setcellgapes{3pt} % <---
    \makegapedcells % <---
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|p{1cm}|X|p{2cm}|} % <---
    \hline
\thead{Task}    & \thead{Description}   & \thead{Points}  % <---                       \\
    \hline
\multirow{14}{=}{\thead{TX.x}} % <---
                & \thead{Test Header}   & \multirow{14}{=}{\centering Example}  \\ 
    \cline{2-2}
                & \lipsum[1]            &                                       \\ 
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]